# Accidental open instead of import of .pst file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst, exchange-2010

A user accidentally opened a archived users `.pst` into their profile instead of importing it.

Now when we try to import the `.pst` into a folder correctly, it says that `This Outlook data file (.pst) is already in use in the current profile`.

Does this mean the profiles have been merged?  Can I unmerge them using a rule; can I restore a backup?

Comment: I renamed the original `.pst` file and now the profile comes up with an error message about the file being missing.

Comment: did you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this PST file from your profile. In Outlook open **File -> Account Settings** and then go to the **Data Files** tab. On this tab select unwanted PST and click **Remove...** button.